# Can I connect an on-premise Release Management server to Visual Studio Online?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, release-management, ms-release-management

I'm working with Release Management and we need to connect RM to TFS which is on VSO.  In VSO we have several accounts set up with LiveIDs - eg xyz@outlook.com - however in Release Management we require a service account (DOMAIN\USERNAME).

Is there any way I can add the local service account (DOMAIN\USERNAME) to our VSO project?  If not, how can I specify a LiveID from within RM's Administration > Manage TFS interface?

Answer (score 2):

On-prem Release Management server does not work with Visual Studio Online, and it never will. Visual Studio Online has a hosted release management service, which only supports vNext release templates and releases to Azure environments.

Visual Studio Online and TFS will be getting a new, totally redesigned release management experience later this year, with no separate client/server.

Answer (score 0):

And, to add to what Daniel said, the new release management in TFS on-premise will have the option to connect to Visual Studio Online to pull down builds.